# Migration does not work in Visual Studio CTP 6 vNext project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I create a new project ASP.NET 5 Preview Starter Web.

Hit Ctrl+F5 to test the project, and works fine.

In Package Manager Console I execute these commands:

```
cd src
cd MyProject
k ef migration add initial
```

as result:

```
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
```

Now I execute:

```
k ef migration apply
```

So, I get these errors:

```
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
k : System.InvalidOperationException: A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use.
At line:1 char:1
+ k ef migration apply
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.InvalidO... string to use.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.RelationalConnection..ctor(DbContextService`1 options, ILoggerFactory l
oggerFactory)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection..ctor(DbContextService`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exce‡Æo foi gerada ---
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.ConstructorCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   em Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredServiceChecked[TService](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.DataStoreSource`2.get_StoreServices()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.DataStoreSelector.SelectDataStore(ServiceProviderSource providerSource)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextServices.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Initialize>b__0()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextServices.get_DataStoreServices()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.DataStoreServices.GetStoreServices(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.DataStoreServices.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<get_DatabaseFactory>b__1()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextService`1.get_Service()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.get_Database()
   em WebApplication17.Models.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() na C:\users\paulo.larini\documents\visual studio 14\Projects\WebApplication17\src\WebApplication17\Models\IdentityModels.cs:linha 27
```

This is supposed to be working, or not?

### UPDATE - 1

After apply the Aqua from mars changes, I got these errors:

```
k : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'NormalizedEmail-' does not exist in table 'AspNetUsers'.
At line:1 char:1
+ k ef migration apply
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Data.Sql... 'AspNetUsers'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Act
ion`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.SqlStatementExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<ExecuteNonQuery>b__0()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.SqlStatementExecutor.Execute(RelationalConnection connection, Func`1 action)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.SqlStatementExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, IEnumerable`1 sqlBatches)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 sqlStatements, RelationalConnection connection)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.ExecuteSqlBatches(IEnumerable`1 sqlBatches)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.ApplyMigration(Int32 index, Boolean simulate)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<ApplyMigrations>b__5(Int32 i)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__8`2.MoveNext()
   em System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.ApplyMigrations(Int32 targetMigrationIndex, Boolean simulate)
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Infrastructure.Migrator.ApplyMigrations()
   em Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.MigrationsEnabledDatabase.ApplyMigrations()
   em WebApplication20.Models.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() na C:\users\paulo.larini\documents\visual studio 14\Projects\WebApplication20\src\WebApplication20\Models\IdentityModels.cs:linha 27
ClientConnectionId:00f13700-00da-40b8-af96-a330a029fdee
Error Number:4924,State:1,Class:16
```

Answer (score 0):

It works only if you configure your connection in `OnConfiringMethod`

```
#if DEBUG  
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptions options)
{
     options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=localSQLdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
     base.OnConfiguring(options);
}
#endif
```

## RESPONSE TO UPDATE - 1

There's issue on code generated in this release (CTP 6)
To fix it update the migration code like this :
`Migration\DATE_initial.cd`

```
    public override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

....

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("AspNetUsers", "NormalizedEmail"); \\ remove the -

....

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(false), \\ set Id not nullable
                    Name = c.String()
                })
            .PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", t => t.Id);

 ....

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable("AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(false), \\ set Id not nullable
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
 ....
```

Comment: After do this, a re run apply command and got the error on my update 1.

Comment: I never test to drop column, maybe there's an issue. What is the kre you use ?

Comment: K Version Manager - Build 10319

Comment: What exactly you ask me to do ?

Comment: What is the runtime you use ? execute `kvm list`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73794/discussion-between-paulo-and-agua-from-mars).

Answer (score 0):

CTP 6 has too many bugs in this point.

I will wait for a next release.